# Angular templating with Dustjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, angularjs-routing, dust.js

I'm a beginner in the AngularJS environmnent. In the interest of my company, I would like to combine the power of the Angular framework with the Dustjs templating engine.

The problem is : Dustsjs is compiling files to .js files (I have a [Grunt task](https://github.com/vtsvang/grunt-dust) which is doing that for me in my public folder), not in .html. And, in the documentation of *$routeProvider*, the 'templateUrl' or 'template' parameters are looking for .html templates.

My app.js :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/', {
    template: 'views/myView.js',
    controller: 'HomeController'
  });
}]);
```

As you can imagine, I have a weird result since my .js is injected without being parsed.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JkRx.jpg

So, my two questions are :
 - Am I doing it right to put the .js file path inside the template of routeProvider, or is there another way to get and correctly display the view? In short, what did I do wrong?
 - Are there any best practices for combining these two technologies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - Am I doing it right to put the .js file path inside the template of routeProvider, or is there another way to get and correctly display
>     the view? In short, what did I do wrong?

No you are not right in putting the .js file path. Angular expects it to a HTML markup.

```
template: '<div>content</div>',
```

and

```
templateUrl : 'views/myview.html'
```

would be acceptable values.

> - Are there any best practices for combining these two technologies?

One of the ways to go would be to use dust templates as the outer template and let angular routeProvider take care of rendering the dynamic content to be parsed by angular. For example,

home.dust

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{page_title}</title>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="myApp">
    {>header/}
    <div ng-view></div>
    {>footer/}
  </body>
</html>
```

header.dust

```
<div id="menu">Menu</div>
```

footer.dust

```
<div id="copyright">Footer</div>
```

view/myView.html

```
<div id="content">Hi ((username))</div>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$interpolateProvider', function ($routeProvider, $interpolateProvider) {
  //This is required as dust templates also '{' and '}' for interpolation
  $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('((').endSymbol('))');
  $routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/myView.html',
    controller: 'HomeController'
  });
}])
.controller('HomeController', function($scope){
$scope.username = "John Doe";
});
```

Comment: Did you mean : `template: 'views/myView.html'` instead of `.js` in the routeProvider configuration? And how could I get one .html file if Dust compiles in .js ?

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake. I've fixed it in the edit above. I meant `templateUrl: 'views/myView.html'`. The trick is to not compile the templates used in angular code. See this [example](https://github.com/chetanhs/xpress-ng-seed). This seed project uses `jade` and not `dust` but the concept remains the same. All your `.dust` files would go inside the `views` folder and would be compiled. All the angular templates would go inside `public/partials` folder and would not be compiled.